# get_post_title is not working on homepage

Tags: plugins, shortcode

My simple shortcode works on all pages except for the homepage (static) in Wordpress 2016 Theme. All content I can read except for the post title. It comes back empty. I want to display posts on homepage with titles. It all works. However the title is blank. Thanks,

```
//Recent post shortcode single
function mfbs_recent_post1x1($atts){
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => '4')
    );
    $list = '<div class="row mfbs1x1">';
    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $title = $q->the_post()->post_title;
        $list .= '<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">';
        $list .= $title;
        $list .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' ;
        $list .= get_the_post_thumbnail($the_post->ID , 'medium', array( 'class' =>     'alignleft' ) );
        $list .= '<br>' . get_the_title() .  '</a>' . '<br>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('foodrecentpost1x1', 'mfbs_recent_post1x1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a query inside a query at this point. Because of that you need to define `global $post` at the top of your functions file so it has something to assign in `the_post()`. Now that you have a `$post` object you can replace all your test code with `$post->attribute`:

```
//Recent post shortcode single
function mfbs_recent_post1x1($atts){
    global $post;
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array( 'orderby' => 'date', 'posts_per_page' => '4')
    );
    $list = '<div class="row mfbs1x1">';
    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $list .= '<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">';
        $list .= $title;
        $list .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' ;
        $list .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID , 'medium', array( 'class' =>     'alignleft' ) );
        $list .= '<br>' . get_the_title() .  '</a>' . '<br>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode('foodrecentpost1x1', 'mfbs_recent_post1x1');
```

Comment: That worked Howdy. Something so simple got me stumped.